# Simplifying ansible file checks?

Tags: ansible

In ansible I'm doing a lot of this:

```
- name: Check if [someFile] exists on host
  stat: path=[someFile]
  register: someFile

- fail: msg="[someFile] not found"
  when: someFile.stat.exists == False
```

I'd like to be able to express it more succinctly. Something like this:

```
- fail_on_missing_file: 
  path: [someFile]
```

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: With Ansible, it's common practice to describe the state you want the target to be in when the playbook has run. In this case, your state is that a file *should* exist, but you do not know what the contents should be - is that correct? (otherwise, the copy or template modules would do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `failed_when` to do what you want:

```
- stat: path=/path/to/some/file
  register: someFile
  failed_when: not someFile.stat.exists
```